# How to put quotation marks ("") into quotation marks?

Tags: c++, cin, cout, ofstream

I have a problem to create .vbs file becouse this "" cannot put it into "".
There is example:
Where is batch<<"echo x=msgbox(" <-- and this quotation marks is blocking the last one. How can I make it work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ofstream batch;
    batch.open("name.bat");
    batch<<"@echo off";
    batch<<"echo x=msgbox("Your Text Here" ,0, "Your Title Here") >> msgbox.vbs";
    batch<<
    batch.close();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Escape them with \.

Comment: Use `\\`, like "echo x=msgbox(\"Your Text Here\" ,0, \"Your Title Here\") >> msgbox.vbs"

Comment: Or raw string: `batch<< R"(echo x=msgbox("Your Text Here" ,0, "Your Title Here") >> msgbox.vbs)";`.

Comment: @JsonFile191 Why you gave up and delete your question about `error: src_path = open"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Fol\text.jpg"`? I would be glad to help you fix the error, but you deleted the question, so I'm leaving a comment here if you still need help.